# PostgreSQL DROP TABLE in a loop fails with ERROR: out of shared memory

Tags: postgresql, locking, out-of-memory, plpgsql

I have a database with a lot (3000+) of schema identical in structure. I'm trying to drop two tables from each schema. So I wrote a function that will loop over the schema and try to drop those tables.

When I execute my function I get ERROR: out of shared memory and no tables get dropped.

**Is there a possibility to force PostgreSQL to commit the drop table statements in batches?**

Here is my function (simplified to the problem in question):

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION utils.drop_webstat_from_schema(schema_name character varying default '')
  RETURNS SETOF record AS
$BODY$
declare
    s record;
    sql text;
BEGIN
    for s in 
        select distinct t.table_schema from information_schema.tables t
        where 
                schema_name <> '' and t.table_schema = schema_name 
                or 
                schema_name = '' and t.table_schema like 'myprefix_%'
    loop
        sql := 'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ' || s.table_schema || '.webstat_hit, ' || s.table_schema || '.webstat_visit';
        execute sql;
        raise info '%; -- OK', sql;
        return next s;
    end loop;
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100
  ROWS 1000;
```

As you can see, the function loops over the set of schema and for each schema the following SQL is constructed and then executed.

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS <schema_name>.webstat_hit, <schema_name>.webstat_visit
```

I guess PostgreSQL is trying to lock all those tables before drop and it reached the max configured limit. 
Probably if I increase the **max_locks_per_transaction** to a certain fixed number I might manage to lock all the tables and drop them.

But **I'm looking for a solution that will drop tables in steps and lock only those tables inside the step**. Like for every 10 schema, lock and drop in a batch.

Can I do that in PostgreSQL and if so, how? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd take schema loop out of the function with drops.

So lets assume `fn_loop`  plpgsql loops schemas and calls `fn_drop`.  You can commit in batches in plpgsql if you execute `fn_drop` over dblink.

Another way to have commit between schemas, loop in bash, eg:

```
for i in $(psql -c "select nspname form pg_namespaces where blah blah"); do
  psql -c "drop damn table";
done;
```

example of local calls in different transaction with dblink (notice difference in now() on same db):

```
t=# do
$$
declare
  _t text;
begin
  for _r in 1..2 loop
    select t into _t from dblink('dbname=t'::text,'select now()::text'::text) rtn (t text);
    raise info '%',concat('local: ',now(),', dblink: ',_t);

  end loop;
end;
$$
;
INFO:  local: 2017-04-28 07:38:11.352026+00, dblink: 2017-04-28 07:38:11.355149+00
INFO:  local: 2017-04-28 07:38:11.352026+00, dblink: 2017-04-28 07:38:11.358211+00
DO
Time: 6.811 ms
```

Comment: yes - that is the whole idea, to have commits inside function, use dblink to localhost, same db